# How to create datatables with server side in codeigniter using sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, datatables, server-side-scripting

I have a problem with datatables serve side processing using SQL Server/MSSQL,
i've been following or use this tutorial [link](http://mbahcoding.com/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-ajax-crud-using-bootstrap-modals-and-datatable.html) but its quite difficult to modify it using sql server

In sql server doesn't allow using limit, i try to use this code below but it wont work

```
SELECT *
      FROM
          ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as NroFila

            FROM  mytables

           ) AS PAG_TABLEXXX

      WHERE
      NroFila BETWEEN 0 AND 10
```

and this the function made my datatables wont work.

```
function get_datatables()
{
    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    if($_POST['length'] != -1)
    $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

this is the erro show, im using firebug to get error.

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:  odbc_exec(): SQL error:
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Executing  SQL
>   directly; no cursor., SQL state 01000 in SQLExecDirect
>
> Filename: odbc/odbc_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 138